General solution for passing names of expressions with selectors in polars
In polars (1.7.1), it does not appear to be straightforward to pass the names of expressions though various operations.
The below is related to the problem identified in How do you access a column name in a polars expression? however I feel that it's sufficiently different that it warrants splitting out.
More generally, the problem is one in which we want to apply expressions that involve multiple columns (strictly, multiple input expressions), where we want to make sure that the name we end up with is preserved based on the "anchor" expression, i.e., the one on which the method is called (self._lhs_expr in the below).
Below is a self-contained example illustrating this.
import traceback
import polars as pl


@pl.api.register_expr_namespace("new")
class NewExtensions:
    _lhs_expr: pl.Expr

    def __init__(self, lhs_expr: pl.Expr):
        # Capture the expression on which the methods are to be called.
        self._lhs_expr = lhs_expr

    def reorder_1(self, weight: pl.Expr) -> pl.Expr:
        # This does not seem to work correctly, despite the superficial expectation it would.
        return weight.sort_by(self._lhs_expr).alias(self._lhs_expr.meta.output_name())

    def reorder_2(self, weight: pl.Expr) -> pl.Expr:
        # This "works". It is a kludge that may have unintended consequences, and is not necessarily generalisable to other types.
        return (self._lhs_expr * 0) + weight.sort_by(self._lhs_expr)


df = pl.DataFrame(
    data=dict(
        weight=[5.1, 4.1, 3.1, 2.1, 1.1], a=[1, 5, 3, 4, 2], b=[-3, -2, -5, -2, -4]
    )
)

# Working.
print(
    "Following works.  Note that the reordering of weight is labeled as 'a' as required."
)
print(
    df.select(
        pl.col("weight"),
        pl.col("a").new.reorder_1(pl.col("weight")),
    )
)


# First failure mode, despite the .alias() inside .reorder_1(), the output name of .new.reorder_1() is weight_reorder
print(
    "Following almost works, except the output name is not a_reorder, but weight_reorder!"
)
print(
    df.select(
        pl.col("a"),
        pl.col("weight"),
        pl.col("a").new.reorder_1(pl.col("weight")).name.suffix("_reorder"),
    )
)

# Second (exception) failure mode, using a selector means the names don't get correctly fixed.
print(
    "The following throws an exception, as it cannot determine the names of all the columns."
)
try:
    print(df.select(pl.selectors.numeric().new.reorder_1(pl.col("weight"))))
except pl.exceptions.ComputeError as e:
    print(traceback.format_exc())


# Working kludge.
print(
    "The following 'works', including the name flowing through to .suffix() but it cannot possibly be the right way to do this."
)
print(df.select(pl.selectors.numeric().new.reorder_2(pl.col("weight")).name.suffix("_")))

This problem is also evident in the polars documentation itself, in the example of the decorator register_expr_namespace, reproduced below.
def register_expr_namespace(name: str) -> Callable[[type[NS]], type[NS]]:
    """
    Decorator for registering custom functionality with a Polars Expr.

    Parameters
    ----------
    name
        Name under which the functionality will be accessed.

    See Also
    --------
    register_dataframe_namespace: Register functionality on a DataFrame.
    register_lazyframe_namespace: Register functionality on a LazyFrame.
    register_series_namespace: Register functionality on a Series.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> @pl.api.register_expr_namespace("pow_n")
    ... class PowersOfN:
    ...     def __init__(self, expr: pl.Expr):
    ...         self._expr = expr
    ...
    ...     def next(self, p: int) -> pl.Expr:
    ...         return (p ** (self._expr.log(p).ceil()).cast(pl.Int64)).cast(pl.Int64)
    ...
    ...     def previous(self, p: int) -> pl.Expr:
    ...         return (p ** (self._expr.log(p).floor()).cast(pl.Int64)).cast(pl.Int64)
    ...
    ...     def nearest(self, p: int) -> pl.Expr:
    ...         return (p ** (self._expr.log(p)).round(0).cast(pl.Int64)).cast(pl.Int64)
    >>>
    >>> df = pl.DataFrame([1.4, 24.3, 55.0, 64.001], schema=["n"])
    >>> df.select(
    ...     pl.col("n"),
    ...     pl.col("n").pow_n.next(p=2).alias("next_pow2"),
    ...     pl.col("n").pow_n.previous(p=2).alias("prev_pow2"),
    ...     pl.col("n").pow_n.nearest(p=2).alias("nearest_pow2"),
    ... )
    shape: (4, 4)
    ┌────────┬───────────┬───────────┬──────────────┐
    │ n      ┆ next_pow2 ┆ prev_pow2 ┆ nearest_pow2 │
    │ ---    ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---          │
    │ f64    ┆ i64       ┆ i64       ┆ i64          │
    ╞════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪══════════════╡
    │ 1.4    ┆ 2         ┆ 1         ┆ 1            │
    │ 24.3   ┆ 32        ┆ 16        ┆ 32           │
    │ 55.0   ┆ 64        ┆ 32        ┆ 64           │
    │ 64.001 ┆ 128       ┆ 64        ┆ 64           │
    └────────┴───────────┴───────────┴──────────────┘

In the above, because the resulting columns have their names explicitly set, everything works fine, however the default names are "literal", rather than the more intuitive name of whatever self._expr would be.
This is a maddeningly frustrating problem, and it really isn't clear what the correct solution should be.

Thanks for adding the python syntax highlighting!

It seems there are different rules for literals. e.g. (2 * pl.all()) raises a DuplicateError, but (2 * pl.all()).name.suffix("") actually works (and uses pl.all() as the root names?) But your example pl.col("w").sort_by(pl.exclude("w")) gets transformed into pl.col("w").sort_by("x"), pl.col("w").sort_by("y") and Polars doesn't seem to offer any way to keep the "last names" (i.e. x and y) in this case.

Perhaps it's something worthy of a feature request on Github.

My thoughts exactly, I just want to make sure it's not a stupid question (and therefore a waste of their time), first.

Unfortunately, there is no right way to do what you want because of this note.

This will undo any previous renaming operations on the expression.


Due to implementation constraints, this method can only be called as the last expression in a chain. Only one name operation per expression will work. Consider using .name.map for advanced renaming.

There are two three workarounds that I can think of.

Have a name parameter in your function so you use that instead of trying to use .name which you know won't work. That name parameter takes a callable much like how name.map works.

Much like your approach in reorder_2 use a struct by using the column you want to be the default name as the first column. The second column is the calculation. Outside of the struct, you rename the fields and then extract the second column. If no other naming operation is performed then your renaming of the struct prevails. If someone calls a .name on it then the first column of the struct is used. Either way it's the same effect of preserving that name. Since polars doesn't copy data this isn't as bad as the syntax suggests.

Use map_batches to call alias. This works because map_batches will force the execution of the expr into a Series which sidesteps the "implementation constraints". In my example below I put the map_batches at the end but it might be better to call it earlier. The issue with map_batches is that it is subject to the python GIL so if you were doing a different map_batches operation on several columns then they wouldn't be in parallel. I'm not sure if the pre-map_batches operations would still be in parallel and then only the renaming part would be serial, it seems it would, in which case renaming is trivial enough that I wouldn't expect it to matter that it isn't parallel. If you use is_elementwise=True in map_batches then it wouldn't even break streaming.


Here they are
@pl.api.register_expr_namespace("new")
class NewExtensions:
    _lhs_expr: pl.Expr

    def __init__(self, lhs_expr: pl.Expr):
        # Capture the expression on which the methods are to be called.
        self._lhs_expr = lhs_expr


    def name_alias(self, 
                   weight: pl.Expr, 
                   map_alias: Callable[[str], str]|None=None) -> pl.Expr:
        root_out = self._lhs_expr.meta.output_name()
        if map_alias is not None:
            root_out=map_alias(root_out)
        return weight.sort_by(self._lhs_expr).alias(root_out)
    
    def struct_hack(self, weight: pl.Expr) -> pl.Expr:
        return (
            pl.struct(
                self._lhs_expr, 
                weight.sort_by(self._lhs_expr)
                )
                .struct.rename_fields(['zzz', self._lhs_expr.meta.output_name()])
                .struct.field(self._lhs_expr.meta.output_name())
        )
    def map_b(self, weight: pl.Expr) -> pl.Expr:
        return weight.sort_by(self._lhs_expr).map_batches(lambda x: (
            x.alias(self._lhs_expr.meta.output_name())
        ))

How they each work in practice
df.select(
    pl.col('a').new.struct_hack(pl.col('weight')).name.suffix('fjf'),
    pl.col('a').new.name_alias(pl.col('weight'), lambda x: f"{x}_zzz")
    )

shape: (5, 2)
┌──────┬───────┐
│ afjf ┆ a_zzz │
│ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ f64  ┆ f64   │
╞══════╪═══════╡
│ 5.1  ┆ 5.1   │
│ 1.1  ┆ 1.1   │
│ 3.1  ┆ 3.1   │
│ 2.1  ┆ 2.1   │
│ 4.1  ┆ 4.1   │
└──────┴───────┘

As a complete aside may I recommend adding this to your functions
def some_func(self, rhs: str | pl.Expr)->pl.Expr:
    if isinstance(rhs, str):
        rhs=pl.col(rhs)
    ...

### Now you can do
df.select(pl.col('a').new.some_func('z'))
# or if you like verbosity you can still do
df.select(pl.col('a').new.some_func(pl.col('z')))


I think your struct_hack idea has legs.  It works a charm with the lhs expression is a single column, but fails when the lhs expression is a selector with multiple columns.  Regarding your aside, yes, noted, I wanted to keep the word count down! :)  It's another bugbear of mine that the polars ecosystem does not appear to allow a string or column object to be used more interchangably by default.  I'm going to experiment with your struct approach and see if I can improve on it.  The polars documentation does say it is the "idomatic way of working with multiple columns".

I ended up going around in circles with struct, as at some point we have to unpack it, and then we're right back where we started assigning names if selector expressions are being used.  It makes me wonder if there is something a bit 'off' with the selector mechanism.

@user1383092 your comment from the other question gave me an idea for a third workaround.

This is what I like to hear! (rubbing hands with glee!) :-)

Sadly that doesn't solve the general case with selectors, due to a problem with meta.output_name() in alias.  I did try swapping the order as well, that map_batches operates on self._lhs_expr, but I could not get it to work.  If you have return self._lhs_expr.map_batches(lambda x: x) you'll see that (as expected) it plays well with selectors, however I can't seem to do what I want to do inside the lambda.  It's a step forwards though.

To be more concrete, imagine this function: def swap_args(values, weights):
return weights.sort_by(values) - I got that idea from the ufunc discussion in another question, note that the "values" is first.   Then I tried:
def map_b(self, weight: pl.Expr) -> pl.Expr:
    return self._lhs_expr.map_batches(lambda x: do_it(x,weight))

Sadly I end up with a result that makes no sense to me, but it feels like a kind of progress.

@user1383092 You can do pl.struct(expr=pl.struct(pl.exclude("weight")), weight=pl.col("weight")).map_batches(lambda s: s.struct.unnest().unnest("expr").select(pl.col("weight").sort_by(c).alias(c) for c in s.struct["expr"].struct.fields).to_struct()) but you can't add .struct.field("*") because the schema/dtype needs to be known. wildcard selectors/exclude/etc are all resolved inside the frame where it can read the schema - which is why output_name() doesn't work for them.

you can't do self._lhs_expr.map_batches(lambda x: do_it(x,weight)) the variable x is a Series from self._lhs_expr. If you want both columns available in the map_batches you have to put them in a struct and then use map_batches` off that.

I think I have a working solution, and would appreciate feedback.
It is a generalization of the original multiply-by-zero-and-add approach, however the trick is to use a .when, .then, .otherwise.  In this, the values of .then are (in principle) never evaluated, however the name(s) is/are applied to the resulting expression(s).
Code
import polars as pl
from typing import Union


@pl.api.register_expr_namespace("new")
class NewExtensions:
    _lhs_expr: pl.Expr

    def __init__(self, lhs_expr: pl.Expr):
        # Capture the expression on which the methods are to be called.
        self._lhs_expr = lhs_expr

    def reorder_3(self, weight: Union[pl.Expr, str]) -> pl.Expr:
        if isinstance(weight, str):
            weight = pl.col(weight)
        # This appears to work in a more generic manner than reorder_2 in the original example.
        return (
            pl.when(False) 
            .then(self._lhs_expr) 
            .otherwise(weight.sort_by(self._lhs_expr))
        )


df = pl.DataFrame(
    data=dict(
        weight=[5.1, 4.1, 3.1, 2.1, 1.1], 
             a=[1, 5, 3, 4, 2], 
             b=[-3, -2, -5, -2, -4],
             c=["cat","dog","giraffe","bear","monkey"]
    )
)

# Working with single column, specified using a string.
print(df.select(pl.col("a").new.reorder_3("weight")))

# Working with a selector, specified using pl.col(), also allowing name.suffix.
print(df.with_columns(pl.selectors.all().new.reorder_3(pl.col("weight")).name.suffix("_")))

Output
shape: (5, 1)
┌─────┐
│ a   │
│ --- │
│ f64 │
╞═════╡
│ 5.1 │
│ 1.1 │
│ 3.1 │
│ 2.1 │
│ 4.1 │
└─────┘
shape: (5, 8)
┌────────┬─────┬─────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ weight ┆ a   ┆ b   ┆ c       ┆ weight_ ┆ a_  ┆ b_  ┆ c_  │
│ ---    ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ f64    ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ str     ┆ f64     ┆ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ str │
╞════════╪═════╪═════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 5.1    ┆ 1   ┆ -3  ┆ cat     ┆ 1.1     ┆ 5.1 ┆ 3.1 ┆ 2.1 │
│ 4.1    ┆ 5   ┆ -2  ┆ dog     ┆ 2.1     ┆ 1.1 ┆ 1.1 ┆ 5.1 │
│ 3.1    ┆ 3   ┆ -5  ┆ giraffe ┆ 3.1     ┆ 3.1 ┆ 5.1 ┆ 4.1 │
│ 2.1    ┆ 4   ┆ -2  ┆ bear    ┆ 4.1     ┆ 2.1 ┆ 4.1 ┆ 3.1 │
│ 1.1    ┆ 2   ┆ -4  ┆ monkey  ┆ 5.1     ┆ 4.1 ┆ 2.1 ┆ 1.1 │
└────────┴─────┴─────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘

I am pretty comfortable that this should do the right thing with names, however, I'd like someone's opinion on if the .then(), of  .when().then().otherwise() is ever used
, e.g., copied, or it would have a material impact on performance.  My expectation is no, as it appears polars is pretty smart when it comes to evaluating a chain of expressions, particularly when operating in Lazy mode.  Given that, aside from picking up the name, it should be a noop!
If people think this is the best we can do, perhaps we should bring this broader issue to the attention of the polars team.  It feels like there should be a standard, hack-free, way of doing this.

then() is always evaluated. All branches are executed in parallel.

Right, poor word choice I'll adjust my answer. https://docs.pola.rs/api/python/stable/reference/expressions/api/polars.when.html#:~:text=Polars%20computes%20all%20expressions%20passed%20to%20when%2Dthen%2Dotherwise%20in%20parallel%20and%20filters%20afterwards.%20This%20means%20each%20expression%20must%20be%20valid%20on%20its%20own%2C%20regardless%20of%20the%20conditions%20in%20the%20when%2Dthen%2Dotherwise%20chain. but does "evaluating" the expression mean anything if it's not used, i.e., does it have any material consequence.

I think it depends on what expr is. e.g. if you did pl.col("a").map_elements(print).new.reorder_3() - it should print everything twice due to double execution.

Hmmm... Food for thought. You mean like this right?
rs = df.select(pl.selectors.all().map_elements(print,return_dtype=str).new.reorder_3(weight="b"))
In which each column of rs becomes a string representation of the weight column, and the value of the sort column is printed twice.  Nice example! :-).  I'm starting to think that there is something fundamentally wrong with this line of thought, and that we simply "should not do it this way", but then, what's the right way.  Stuff like this is very easy in R data.table, it feels like this should be easy.

Yes, I think another issue is c_ has a type of str here due to the when/then implicit casting. I'm not exactly sure why this is apparently such a difficult thing to implement.

Just as a follow-up to your when/then approach.
It appears this is actually possible using .replace_strict() + .fill_null()
lhs_expr = pl.exclude("weight")
weight = pl.col("weight")

expr = (
   lhs_expr
    .replace_strict(None, None, default=None)
    .fill_null(weight.sort_by(lhs_expr))
)

df.with_columns(expr.name.suffix("_reorder"))

shape: (5, 7)
┌────────┬─────┬─────┬─────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ weight ┆ a   ┆ b   ┆ c       ┆ a_reorder ┆ b_reorder ┆ c_reorder │
│ ---    ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---     ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ f64    ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ str     ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       │ # <- c_* keeps f64 ✓
╞════════╪═════╪═════╪═════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 5.1    ┆ 1   ┆ -3  ┆ cat     ┆ 5.1       ┆ 3.1       ┆ 2.1       │
│ 4.1    ┆ 5   ┆ -2  ┆ dog     ┆ 1.1       ┆ 1.1       ┆ 5.1       │
│ 3.1    ┆ 3   ┆ -5  ┆ giraffe ┆ 3.1       ┆ 5.1       ┆ 4.1       │
│ 2.1    ┆ 4   ┆ -2  ┆ bear    ┆ 2.1       ┆ 4.1       ┆ 3.1       │
│ 1.1    ┆ 2   ┆ -4  ┆ monkey  ┆ 4.1       ┆ 2.1       ┆ 1.1       │
└────────┴─────┴─────┴─────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘

The replace_strict creates an all null selection which can be filled while keeping the names.
df.select(lhs_expr.replace_strict(None, None, default=None))

shape: (5, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ a    ┆ b    ┆ c    │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ null ┆ null ┆ null │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ null ┆ null ┆ null │
│ null ┆ null ┆ null │
│ null ┆ null ┆ null │
│ null ┆ null ┆ null │
│ null ┆ null ┆ null │
└──────┴──────┴──────┘

This seems to avoid both potential issues with the when/then approach:

double evaluation of lhs_expr
implicit supertype casting


Update: It seems only a single row is needed for this to work.
i.e. just running .first() through the replace seems to avoid a very slight overhead when testing on a larger example.
df.select(lhs_expr.first().replace_strict(None, None, default=None))

shape: (1, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ a    ┆ b    ┆ c    │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ null ┆ null ┆ null │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ null ┆ null ┆ null │
└──────┴──────┴──────┘

(Although I'm not entirely sure I understand how the fill_null still works in this case?)

This is great! By which I mean the best hacky work-around yet! :-)  It's very similar to an idea I had with coalesce, but the polars API is alien to me, so I didn't know where to look or how to make it work.  I've abstracted this as: def rename(expr: pl.Expr, name_expr: pl.Expr) -> pl.Expr:
"""Return expression expr, but in a way that it adopts the name of name_expr."""
return name_expr.first().replace_strict(None, None, default=None).fill_null(expr)
So now, we can use "rename" as the first part of an expression to make sure the result adopts that name.

I'm going to see what else may pop up from people over this week, and then try and write an authoritative solution to this, combining what everyone has contributed.  Once that's "stable", I think it makes sense to highlight the answer to the polars developers so there is an official way of doing this.  My bet is that whatever we come up with will have some edge case with unexpected or unintuitive side-effects.  What do you think?

Perhaps this should be called "alias", and be how alias should work by default, i.e., https://docs.pola.rs/api/python/stable/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.alias.html should accept an argument of type str (current behaviour), or polars.Expr (this behaviour).

Yes, I don't think this has any side effects - but it's possible I've missed something. It seems like it may need some new .name.*() type method added? Because it effectively has to turn pl.col("weight").sort_by(pl.exclude("weight")) into pl.col("weight").sort_by(pl.col("a")).alias("a") - i.e. you want to use the "tail" expression name instead of the "root". I'm not sure how complex it would be to enable such a thing.
